# PyQt5 - Used QThread to avoid ui hang but it still happens

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to make something parses an website and displays its content on PyQt widget.

I've finished logic part, but IO task hangs the ui for few seconds, making progressbar useless.

So I tried to use threads but it didn't helped.

Here is simplified version of what I'm doing (I'm using PyQt5 on Python 3.4.4, Windows 10)

MainWindow is Qt Designer generated class.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal

class WorkerThread(QThread):
    signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, data):
        QThread.__init__(self)

        self.data = data

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        result = dosomeIOjob(self.data) # IO and parsing job, takes about 3 seconds
        sendsomething(result)

    def sendsomething(self, value):
        self.signal.emit(value)

class UIClass(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, MainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.dosomejob)

    def dosomejob(self):
        data = self.lineedit_search.text()
        self.runworker(self, data)

    def settext(value):
        self.text.setText(value)

    def runworker(self, data):
        worker = WorkerThread(data)
        worker.signal.connect(self.settext)
        worker.run()
```

There's no errors; it just hangs till the job is done.

Am I using pyqtSignal wrong? Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the type (str) along so that `settext` will get it and be able to use it. I've also always used start() as in `worker.start()` instead of run() to start the thread. Not sure that makes a difference, just how I've read/learned it.

here's the code you need to change. 
`worker.signal[str].connect(self.settext)`